# Write ALP to display ASCII characters from 32 to 127 on a defined window (5,10 and 20,70) with white on blue attribute

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086, microprocessors

For this question I have cleared screen as the only for (5,10 and 20, 70) as given in question and set the cursor at (5,10). But it will print all the characters outside the defined window(kind of overflow). I wanted to print all characters inside of defined window only. How can I achieve that??

**Here is my code:**

```
.model small
.stack 64
.data       
.code
    main proc far
        mov ax, @data
        mov ds, ax
        
        mov ax, 0600h
        mov bh, 17h
        mov ch, 5
        mov cl, 10
        mov dh, 20
        mov dl, 70
        int 10h 
        
        mov ah, 02h
        mov bh, 00h
        mov dh, 05h
        mov dl, 0ah
        int 10h 
                  
        mov ah, 02h          
        mov dx, 32 
    l1: int 21h
        inc dx
        cmp dx, 127
        jne l1
        
        mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h
        main endp
    end main
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Neither BIOS (`int 10h`) nor DOS (`int 21h`) will stay in the window that you've cleared to WhiteOnBlue. You have to manage your own linefeeds.

The task asks you to print **96** characters (127 - 32 + 1) in total (ASCII codes 32 to 127).
In a window that runs from leftside 10 to rightside 70 can you fit **61** characters (70 - 10 + 1).

There are of course many good solutions for such a task. Below is one of them.

I've chosen to print a full row with 61 characters and then print the remaining 35 characters on the row beneath. For that I've had to position the cursor a second time.

```
    mov bh, 00h     ; DisplayPage

    mov dx, 050Ah   ; Leftside (10) on 1st row (5) in the window
    mov ah, 02h     ; BIOS.SetCursor
    int 10h
    mov ax, 0E20h   ; BIOS.Teletype starting at ASCII 32
T1: int 10h
    inc al
    cmp al, 93
    jb  T1

    mov dx, 060Ah   ; Leftside (10) on 2nd row (6) in the window
    mov ah, 02h     ; BIOS.SetCursor
    int 10h
    mov ax, 0E5Dh   ; BIOS.Teletype starting at ASCII 93 == 32 + 61
T2: int 10h
    inc al
    cmp al, 128
    jb  T2
```

Additional notes:

- Avoid using labels like `l1`. The smallcaps letter `l` is easily confused with the digit `1`.
- Try to write some meaningful comments in your programs. See what I have written. Especially numbers for which you didn't add a comment get rapidly classified as *magic numbers* and that's something few people like!